# Django read frame returning decimal fields value after rounding or truncating

Tags: django

Django read frame is returning decimal fields value after rounding or truncating. How can this be prevented?

My Django Model

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_index=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    diff = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=5)
    open_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    previous_close = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    low52 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    high52 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField()

    objects = DataFrameManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        self.last_updated = timezone.now()
        return super(Stock, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.code)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8cKa.png)

But when I read data using django readframe then I see

```
In [41]: read_frame(Stock.objects.filter(code='ABB'))
Out[41]: 
   id            name code    price  diff open_price previous_close    low52   high52                     last_updated
0   1  ABB India Ltd.  ABB  1400.00  5.02    1328.60        1325.45  1190.00  1670.00 2019-09-20 14:51:28.666744+00:00
```